# python error in reading number from csv

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I have a csv file like - order_id,name,address
When i try to insert data from csv to postgresql table via python it does not read the number properly.

e.g let data be

```
order_id  |  name  |  address
----------+--------+----------
5432548543| Manish | Dummy Address
```

it reads the order_id like 5.43E+9 instead of whole number. my code is like:

```
filename.encode('utf-8')
with open(filename) as file:
    data = csv.DictReader(file)
    cur.executemany("""Insert into temp_unicom values(%(Order Id)s,%(Name)s,%(Address)s)""", data)
```

Here Order ID, Name, Address are headers of my csv file.

How to correctly format the data?
EDIT::

 Link to csv File [CSV File](http://tempsend.com/233E57699F)

Comment: Maybe the number is read in correctly and you are just displaying it in scientific form? What type is the order_id column?

Comment: It is of varchar type. Because many order id contains alphabets too.

Comment: Do the numbers look right in the csv file?

Comment: If you use a data file with a single entry in it (say the example you gave) - does that have the issue? Does your csv look like the one I posted in my answer? Just trying to figure out if it's an issue on the data side, or the postgres side.

Comment: Most look but some don't. When i expand the column width then they are shown correctly.

Comment: Ah, so it's an interface issue in whatever db viewer you're using? The data is inserted correctly? Just made a couple of edits to your code (you don't need to call `file.close` as the `with` statement does that automatically and the indenting was off, which was confusing).

Comment: I have added a link to csv file

Comment: The problem is in the csv file. There are quite a few lines were the numbers are written in scientific notation. Open the csv in notepad and scroll down a bit to see them.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a process for trying to fix your broken data. OT but Lord it's annoying when you have totally sane edits rejected on SO – thankfully they snuck through with the subsequent edit by the poster.

Comment: try bigint instead of varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change the example you provided to a csv:

```
order_id,name,address
5432548543,Manish,Dummy Address
```

And just iterate over the rows, printing them out:

```
with open('./data.txt') as f:
    data = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in data:
            print(l)
```

I get:

```
{'order_id': '5432548543', 'name': 'Manish', 'address': 'Dummy Address'}
```

Which suggests the issue isn't in the csv parsing step - but you should try the same thing on your data set to double check.

Then the question is - what is your postgres driver doing that could be causing the issue? Are you using psycopg2? Does it do some automatic casting somewhere?

EDIT so the problem is the src data. Sometimes you have ints in scientific notation. You need to scrub the data before passing it to `executemany`:

```
data = csv.DictReader(f)

clean_data = []
for d in data:
    clean_data.append(d)
    try:
        d['Order Id'] = str(int(float(d['Order Id'])))
    except ValueError:
        pass

cur.executemany("""Insert into temp_unicom values (%(Order Id)s, %(Name)s, %(Address)s)""", clean_data)
```

Comment: Issue maybe there in python 2.x?

Comment: Yes i am using psycopg2

Comment: I have some order_ids which contains alphabets with number. Will this code affect them too? I mean if this code will throw any error with alphanumeric order ids?

Comment: No, that's why we use the `try...except` block. Only integers will be effected. Actually, let's turn them back to strings too - to make sure everything is consistent. Will update the answer.

Comment: So an integer will go from '87176421' to 87176421.0 to 87176421 to '87176421' again. Scientific notation will be '5.43E+3' to 5430.0 to 5430 to '5430'. String will be 'some_string' to expection -> pass -> nothing changed (still 'some_string' in the dict).

Comment: The file is not uploading. code says file is uploaded but no new entries are reflected in table

Comment: Are you passing `clean_data` to your `executemany` statement? The `for` loop that cleans the data with 'drain' the csvreader of its rows.

Comment: The important bit is cut off that screenshot - you _need_ to pass `clean_data` to your `executemany`  statement.

Comment: Not Working. Still uploading some order id in scientific notation.

Comment: Do you have a specific example? Are any of the ones that were broken before fixed now?

Comment: I got some lead. In my csv file only those order ids are displayed in scientific notation where channel name is 'Amazon'. So i think only those rows have problem. I am attaching my complete code can you look at it?     http://tempsend.com/1C078A5387

Comment: That code still isn't right. You need to pass in __clean_dict__ to exectuemany. Also, cur.executemany is indented incorrectly - it should be after and outside the for loop.

Comment: It's a little frustrating because you just need to follow my example above. In your code, you have the executemany within the for loop, I don't. Also, I pass in clean_data and you pass in dict.

Comment: Thanx it worked. I was passing dict instead of clean_data. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the float to string before sending the dict.

Example -

```
cur.executemany("""Insert into temp_unicom values(%(Order Id)f,%(Name)s,%(Address)s)""",dict((k,v )if k != "Order Id" else (k,'%f'%(v)) for k,v in dict1.iteritems()))
```

Also, rename the dictionary to something else (I for example renamed to `dict1` , because otherwise it would replace the built-in `dict` function.

Comment: From the pyscopg2 docs (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) "The variables placeholder must always be a %s, even if a different placeholder (such as a %d for integers or %f for floats) may look more appropriate"

Comment: Looking at the docs it looks as though `executemany` should faithfully pass through whichever string is in the dict. It feels like a case where maybe the src data could have the inconsistencies.

Comment: Tried a newer approach on changing the dict itself to hold formatted string, rather than float.